# Reset canvas after error

Tags: html, canvas, error-handling

I'm seeing the following behavior in a WebKit-based browser on embedded device: after there is an error drawing to the canvas (I'm not sure yet exactly about the nature of the error, but some times it looks like as if it failed to draw because the drawing was too slow...), the canvas itself becomes stale. I.e. no more drawing commands will affect the image (the error is caught in JavaScript code).

As right of now I'm not able to fix the error - how would I cause the canvas to refresh, as in recover after drawing error?

Comment: how are we supposed to help if you don't post the error which is "caught in JavaScript code"?

Comment: @Saturnix the error is irrelevant. It can be anything really. The important thing is that canvas becomes stale / can't be affected by drawing / wiping any more.

Comment: it is not - a JS error will interrupt your possibility of drawing on the canvas.

Comment: @Saturnix sorry, I probably didn't explain it clearly: there is some error related to not being able to fit the image in the canvas when using `drawImage` - but this has no importance as 1) I cannot fix it right now, 2) I need to take care of the unfortunate side effect of the error, not the error itself (i.e. the canvas stalls and the calls to the `context.drawImage` no longer result in canvas being updated, even though they no longer cause an error.)

Comment: I'm telling you, for the third time, that the error you see IS causing the canvas to crash. No matter what you do after, if drawImage cause an error you will NOT be able to update the canvas and, most likely, to execute JavaScript at all. drawImage usually crashes when you try to access an impossible position in an image: access a wrong index of an array will cause your script to crash. How you can recover it? You can't. Avoid calling unexisting array indexes and you'll solve.

Comment: @Saturnix no need to get emotional over it. If you want to repro the bug - just put a `debugger` statement in the code handling the canvas - for me this stalls the canvas about half of the time. But you really could put more effort into trying to understand the question before offering to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to force re-initialization with something like this:

```
try {

//to catch the error you recevie
} catch(err) {

    var tempHeight = canvas.height;
    canvas.height = 0;
    canvas.height = tempHeight;
}
```

(some would say just set `canvas.height = canvas.height` (or width) but this doesn't work in all browsers).

Another approach is to detach the canvas element itself, create a new element and attach that to the original parent with a `attachChild`.

However, these are hacks and hopefully the bug you see will be removed in next update.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, only creating a new canvas element works so far :( But thanks for suggesting more ideas!